# Crash when Replacing Custom Loading View with CircularProgressIndicator in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I'm encountering a crash in my Jetpack Compose app when I attempt to replace a custom loading view with the CircularProgressIndicator from Material Design. Specifically, the crash occurs after my resources have finished loading. The crash report throws a java.lang.StackOverflowError and seems to be related to the Compose runtime, as indicated by the stack trace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8188KB
at java.lang.Object.equals(Object.java:194)
at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.areEqual(Intrinsics.java:169)
at androidx.compose.runtime.GroupSourceInformation.hasAnchor(SlotTable.kt:767)
... (repeat calls to hasAnchor)
```

Below is the code snippet related to this issue. The crash occurs when I replace the commented-out LoadingView() with CircularProgressIndicator():

```
@Composable
private fun TestPageContent(
    // Parameters removed for brevity
    isLoading: Boolean
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Background),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // Other UI components...

        if (isLoading) {
            //LoadingView()
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        } else {
            LazyColumn(
                // Configuration and content...
            ) {
                // Content...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to replace my custom LoadingView() composable with the CircularProgressIndicator() from Material Design. I expected this change to display a circular progress indicator while my resources are loading without causing any issues. However, after the resources finish loading, the app crashes with a StackOverflowError pointing towards Compose runtime internals.

I was anticipating a straightforward replacement since CircularProgressIndicator() is a standard Compose UI element and I assumed it would not affect the app's stability.

The error seems related to the Compose internals, but it's triggered by replacing a custom view with the CircularProgressIndicator, which is quite unusual and could be a bug or might be related to some resource/thread management happening in the background. Any insights or similar experiences shared would be greatly appreciated!

Dependencies

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-alpha06")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.6.0-alpha06")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha08")
```

Edit:

I found the problem. Above the if load control, I have this component:

```
PageTitle(
   modifier = Modifier
      .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
      .zIndex(1f),
   text = "Test"
)
```

Which is :

```
Column(
   modifier = modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .height(50.dp),
) {
   Box(modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
         .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
         .background(color),
      contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
   ) {
      Text(
         text = text,
         fontSize = 24.sp,
         color = titleColor
      )
   }
   Box(
      modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
         .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
   )
}
```

When i remove it, no more crash. But I still don't understand why it crash otherwise

Comment: If you try `CircularProgressIndicator` on empty screen, does it crash too?

Comment: No, and i see the progress on my page, its just when the if condition pass to true, it crash

Comment: Does it crash without both the custom loading UI and Circular Progress Indicator?

Comment: No, it dont. if i remove or add the custom, it work, if i replace my custom loading to the material one, it crash after the loading

Comment: What happens if you put the CircularProgressIndicator before the PageTitle?